# debian unable to automount partition at boot

Tags: debian, mount, boot, fstab

I have a single usb drive connected to my server, and I am unable to get it to automount at boot time. If I manually execute `mount -a` it mounts correctly.

my fstab is as follows:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
UUID=596ac80a-5571-41dc-a00e-b3270ecfe7c4 / ext3 errors=continue 0 1 
/dev/sdb1 /home/teamspeak/ts3/files/virtualserver_1/channel_527 ext3 nofail,defaults,errors=continue 0 0
tmpfs   /var/log   tmpfs   nofail,defaults,noatime,mode=0755,size=5M   0  0
```

Right after boot time this is the output of `df`:

```
/dev/sda1               480935    398349     57754  88% /
tmpfs                   248644         0    248644   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                    244200       128    244072   1% /dev
tmpfs                   248644         0    248644   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     5120       184      4936   4% /var/log
```

then if I `mount -a` it is shown as having mounted correctly:

```
/dev/sda1               480935    398349     57754  88% /
tmpfs                   248644         0    248644   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                    244200       128    244072   1% /dev
tmpfs                   248644         0    248644   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     5120       184      4936   4% /var/log
/dev/sdb1               980284    525744    404744  57% /home/teamspeak/ts3/files/virtualserver_1/channel_527
```

[full dmesg output (boot + successfully mounted volume after mount -a)](http://pastebin.com/qpyeRbKE)

/dev/sdb1 is the drive in question in the above, and the mount point referenced exists.

Comment: What is the output in dmesg just after boot? Is `/dev/sdb1` the drive in question? Does the mount point directory exist?

Comment: Please either paste your relevant dmesg output lines into your post, or at least use a less egregious way of pasting them to a link (such as pastebin). Please also update your post to clarify your drive in question (rather than assuming future readers will see these comments)

Comment: That's doubtful; in any case, when asking for advice, it implies there may be something you've missed!

Answer (score 0):

You may have more success with UUIDs with external drives (as drive namings such as sdb1 are not permanent for external drives);

To find the UUID of the drive in question, execute `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`, then replace the line in `/etc/fstab` which you had previously to use the appropriate UUID, eg:

```
UUID=ABCDEF0123456789 /home/teamspeak/ts3/files/virtualserver_1/channel_527 ext3 nofail,defaults,errors=continue 0 0
```

As an aside, it may also be worthwhile specifying appropriate permissions on the directory in question (particularly as it is in a home directory) and specifying a specific uid and gid in fstab.

Comment: thank you for your reply, unfortunately your suggestion didn't work. It behaves in the same exact way it behaved. Anyway, it wouldn't be of help if I swapped that specific usb drive with another one, in that case I'd need to edit my fstab every time...

Comment: Have you tried mounting it somewhere more conventional, for example `/media/somewhere`?

Comment: Sure. 
I omitted to say that the current mount point is a directory which exists and is part of an already mounted drive (sda1, my hard drive).